# Not able to remove the default record type from Some Standard Community Profile and External Profile

Tags: profile, record-type

"Hello Everyone,

I am attempting to delete a custom record type that was created on the Contact Profile object. However, this record type is set as the default for all profiles. I have tried removing it for all other profiles by accessing the object settings of the respective profiles. However, I am unable to remove the default record type from the standard profiles listed below(For Eg all Community Profiles), as the Contact Profile object is not visible under the object settings. Despite these profiles not having access to the Contact Profile object, an error is still being thrown while I am attempting to delete that particular record type.

Kindly assist us in resolving this issue or suggest a workaround. Your help is much appreciated."
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[According to the Salesforce documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385230&type=1), some standard profiles, such as **Chatter Only**, **Chatter Free**, **Package License Manager**, **Platform Integration User**, and **Salesforce Administrator**, do not allow edits to their assigned record types.

To remove the record type assignment from those profiles, you need to disable the **Enhanced Profile User Interface** feature, and then edit the record type settings for each profile.

- In Salesforce Classic, go to Setup | Manage Users | User Management Settings.
- In Lightning Experience, go to Setup | Users | User Management Settings.
- While within **User Management Settings**, disable **Enhanced Profile User Interface** by toggling the switch from **Enabled** to **Disabled**. Re-enable the feature when done.
- In Salesforce Classic, go to Setup | Manage Users | Profiles.
- In Lightning Experience, go to Setup | Users | Profiles.
- Click the name of the standard profile that you want to edit, such as Chatter Only.
- Scroll down to Record Type Settings and click the Edit link next to the object that includes the record type to remove, such as Account.
- Change the default record type for that profile as desired and save.
  Repeat this step for each object that has a record type to remove.
- Repeat the steps for each standard profile that you want to edit.

This will remove the record type assignment from the standard community profiles in Salesforce.

Comment: Your solution worked just now for me to change the RecordTypes for All Community profiles listed   .
Thank you for sharing your solution!

Comment: In addition to the above steps , there is one more document that can be followed if you don't have access to profiles or you directly want to access the record type page settings page https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008m5fIAA